# Unable to access objects from the html

Tags: python, django

I am making a django project and want to access the characteristics of a user from within the html but am unable to do so can someone please point the mistake in my code?

html

```
  <img height="125px" width="125px" class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ user1.image.url }}">

      <h5 class='pr-2'>{{ user1.user }} </h5>
```

views.py

```
def user_blog_list(request, username):
    user1=Profile.objects.filter(user__username=username)
    context={
    'user1':user1
    }
    return render(request,'blog/user_posts.html',context)
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image=models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)
    description=models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

urls.py

```
path('user/<str:username>',views.user_blog_list,name='user-posts'),
```

Comment: can you add the error you are getting?

Comment: @NotSoShabby nothing is being displayed in the template at all

Comment: try adding a `get_absolute_url` method to the Profile class

Comment: `def get_absolute_url(self): return '/user/{0}/'.format(self.username)`

Comment: @NotSoShabby I have a ```get_absolute_url``` but i dont see how that relates to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`filter` always returns a QuerySet. You need `get`:

```
user1=Profile.objects.get(user__username=username)
```